# Prove $x_n \leq x_{n+1}$ for all $n$ by induction

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, induction

Prove $x_n \leq x_{n+1}$ for all $n$ by induction.

I am reading this example from "Understanding Analysis" by Abbott (page 10).

He says the multiple across the inequality by $1/2$ and then add 1 to get.
$$\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}x_n +1 \leq \frac{1}{2}x_{n+1} +1 \tag{1}
\end{equation}$$
Which leads to 
$$x_{n+1} \leq x_{n+2} \tag{2}$$
I am not quite certain how he went from equation (1) to (2).  I am also not clear why he multiplied across by $1/2$ and added 1; but the previous question might clear up the next question.

Shot of the book page:
[image]

Comment: This is kind'a hard to answer without knowing more about $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$.

Comment: I guess that $x_{n}$ is defined as $$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}[2}x_n+1$$

Comment: What means $x_{n+}$ ? Do you mean $x_{n+1}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base case is clear ($x_1 = 1 \le 3/2 = x_2$). Now assume the induction hypothesis $x_n \le x_{n+1}$, and manipulate it as follows:

$$
x_n \le x_{n+1} \implies \frac{1}{2}x_n \le \frac{1}{2}x_{n+1} \implies \frac{1}{2}x_n +1 \le \frac{1}{2}x_{n+1} + 1 \implies x_{n+1} \le x_{n+2}.
$$